# Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:56557/api/tw/' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy:

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am getting following error.When i tried to send the request from angular 5.0.

**Request header field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.**

(using Postman, the API call works)

following is the angular code

```
let config = {
      headers: {
         "Content-Type": "application/json,charset=utf-8",
         "access-control-allow-origin": "*",
         "access-control-allow-methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS",
         "access-control-allow-headers": "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization"

        }
      }

    let obs = this.httpClient.post('http://localhost:56557/api/tw/',bodypara,config);
```

---

following is the web config changes

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <!--<remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />-->
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <!--<add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />-->
      <add name="Browser Link for HTML" path="*.html" verb="*"
         type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
         resourceType="File" preCondition="integratedMode" />
    </handlers>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules>
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
  <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization" />
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
        </customHeaders>
      </httpProtocol>




  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: The `access-control-allow-*` headers, are all response headers. Remove them from your request. You've also told your app that they are not allowed `<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've told your app that the `access-control-allow-*` headers are not allowed by not including them in the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` options:

```
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization" />
```

Which is why you are seeing the error.

Also, the `access-control-allow-*` headers, are all response headers and would normally be ignored by the server anyway. Simply remove them from your request.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following code at the top of your file on the server.

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With");
```

**In case you set a specific headers in angular or requesting file**

You will need to enter them as seen below:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: [SCHEME]://[HOST]:[PORT_OPTIONAL]
```

---

**SCHEME** => `http/https`

**HOST** => `server ip/domain name`

**PORT_OPTIONAL** => `port //optional`